# How to get domain name in REST API

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, curl

We have create one rest api. And also how to get user domain name from user request process.
Example:
user using my rest api through curl method. Then how to get user domain name / ipaddress in my side.

Comment: $_SERVER{REMOTE_ADDR], $_SERVER[HOST]?

Answer (score 0):

you can try $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. In case of HTTP_REFERER be aware of security risk, It can be faked and doesn't work well with host sharing.